# Formula with a cap and return to 0 if negative

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to create a formula based off of several conditions.

I want my formula to allow me to put a cap on the number while also returning the number to 0 if it becomes negative. This is the formula I currently have.

```
=IF(C3<Sheet1!C4,0,*C3-C4-C5-C6)*
```

The problem is with the last set of data between the `* *`. The cap on this answer is 850,000. So, if C3 is very large, my number exceeds the cap. I feel like there is an easy solution. But I am at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

```
=MIN(MAX(0,C3-C4-C5-C6),850000)
```

If `C3-C4-C5-C6` is negative, returns zero; if it's greater than 850,000, returns 850,000; else returns the result of `C3-C4-C5-C6`.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was making it more complicated than I should have.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without properly understanding your question, I am guessing that you want to cap a number at between 0 and 850000 regardless of what the sum of a figure is.

Therefore, I am assuming that something like this is what you are after:

```
=IF(A2<0,0,IF(A2>850000,850000,A2))
```

[image]

Obviously, you would need to set your ranges so that you weren't statically working from A1,A2,A3 etc and you may even want a reference table like so:

```
=IF(A3<F3,0,IF(A3>F4,F4,A3))
```

[image]

If you move your minimum and maximum to another sheet and stick your "sum of valued" cells in place of A2/A3/etc then this should give you what you are lookg for (again, assuming I've understood your question correctly)

Hope this helps.